# I need to separate a PostgreSQL table in this intercalated format

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, unpivot

I have this query in Postgres:

```
Select 
    "Charges"."saleAmount", "Charges"."buyAmount", "Operations"."id"
From 
    "Charges"
Left Join 
    "Operations" On "Operations"."id" = "Charges"."operationsId"
Order By 
    "Operations"."id"
```

| saleAmount | buyAmount | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | NULL | id1 |
| 300 | 500 | id2 |
| 0 | 100 | id3 |

I need to transform it: Add a new column `type` depending on `saleAmount` > 0 or `buyAmount` > 0, and separate into two rows when I have both `saleAmount` and `buyAmount` in the same row.

| saleAmount | buyAmount | id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | NULL | id1 | sale |
| 300 | 0 | id2 | sale |
| 0 | 500 | id2 | buy |
| 0 | 100 | id3 | buy |

How do I transform my table into this format?

Column `type` can be made with:

```
(CASE
    WHEN "saleAmount" > 0 THEN 'sale'
    WHEN "buyAmount" > 0 THEN 'buy'
 END) as "type"
```

Comment: I've gone and removed the tag spam here since you have stated Postgres. The hint you need is "join"

Comment: On a side note: Why have you made your database case sensitive? Thus you must always use double quotes and remember whether you spelled it "soldout" or "soldOut" etc. Life is easier with case insensitive databases, and it is even the default (just don't use quotes when creating your tables).

Comment: Another side note: You allow both 0 and NULL, but they seem to mean the same thing. If so, why not allow only one of the two to get the data more consistent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` to create two rows out of one. E.g.:

```
Select c."saleAmount", c."buyAmount", o."id", c.type
From 
(
  Select
    "saleAmount",
    Case When "buyAmount" > 0 Then 0 Else "buyAmount" End As "buyAmount",
    'sale' as type
  From "Charges"
  Where "saleAmount" > 0
  Union All
  Select
    Case When "saleAmount" > 0 Then 0 Else "saleAmount" End As "saleAmount",
    "buyAmount",
    'buy' as type
  From "Charges"
  Where "buyAmount" > 0
) c
Left Join "Operations" o On o."id" = c."operationsId"
Order By o."id";
```

The join of the Operations table seems superfluous by the way. Either the Charges has an operationsId, then it links to an Operations row with the same ID or it doesn't have an operationsId, then it doesn't link to Operations row. So why not just show the "Charges"."operationsId" instead of joining to the Operations table just to show the same ID?

Comment: Because is a simplification of a complex query with dozens of joins and cases. I just wanted to be clear with my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a *values* table constructor and use a case expression to determine how many rows qualify for the join:

```
select t.* 
from t
join (
  values(1),(2)
)x(r) on r <= case 
    when Coalesce(saleamount, 0) > 0
     and Coalesce(buyAmount, 0) > 0
    then 2 else 1 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use union all.

```
select
  c.saleAmount,
  0 buyAmount,
  o.id,
  'sale'
from Charges c
  Left Join "Operations" o On o."id" = c."operationsId"
where isnull(c.saleAmount) > 0
union all
select
  0 saleAmount,
  c.buyAmount,
  o.id,
  'buy'
from Charges c
  Left Join "Operations" o On o."id" = c."operationsId"
where isnull(c.buyAmount,0) > 0
```

Comment: This gets you the first and the last row only. Now how to get the second row? End even split in two?

Comment: I changed code, check it now.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You are showing zeros instead of nulls. I suppose that doesn't matter, but that is just an assumption.

Comment: It depends what do you prefer/need. Can you check, that my answear was useful? ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can unpivot the two columns to rows with `values` and a lateral join, then filter out unwanted rows in the `where` clause:

```
select c.*, t.type
from charges c
cross join lateral ( 
    values (c.saleamount, 'sale'), (c.buyamount, 'buy')
) t(amount, type)
where t.amount > 0
```

It is not obvious what the purpose of the `left join` in the original query is, so I left it apart - but you can easily add it to the query if needed.